# Java compile error on OSX but not on Windows

Tags: java, macos, maven-3

I'm running into an issue with Java compile error on OSX but all works fine on Windows 7.

On both platforms I'm using IntelliJ with Java 1.70 u80 SDK and Maven 3.3.9  (bundle from IntelliJ)

The error which appears on OSX is

> incompatible types: Iterator cannot be converted to Iterator

for the code line which looks like

```
Iterator<Node> it = sh.extractAllHeaderElements();
while (it.hasNext())
{
    ...
}
```

Any clue why it works on Windows machine but not on Mac?

Edit:

Imports are:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.*;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.annotation.PreDestroy;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.xml.bind.Element;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPBody;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPElement;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPEnvelope;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPException;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPHeader;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPHeaderElement;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPMessage;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPPart;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.MessageContext;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.soap.SOAPHandler;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.soap.SOAPMessageContext;

import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.nhindirect.xd.soap.type.MetadataLevelEnum;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
```

Comment: Can you please post the full code file, including imports on the top of the page?

Comment: Try Changing this line `Iterator<Node> it = sh.extractAllHeaderElements();` to `Iterator<Node> it = (Iterator<Node>) sh.extractAllHeaderElements();`

Comment: I'd guess the imports are different between the two source files.  Try checking that.

Comment: @SteelToe I have added imports to the OP. Full code is to big to post it here (1000+ lines)

Comment: Is this the same file that you are compiling on both mac and windows? or is it two different files?

Comment: @SteelToe I have replace the code - still the same issue.

Comment: @SteelToe this is the same file which I try to compile on OSX

Comment: Try using a raw version of Iterator, such as this `Iterator it = sh.extractAllHeaderElements();` or a wildcard version like this `Iterator<?> it = sh.extractAllHeaderElements();`

Comment: I'd be a little concerned about the `*` characters in the imports.  [These are kind of bug prone](http://javadude.com/articles/importondemandisevil.html).  Try replacing them with the actual imports that you're using.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem I agree that imports on demand are bug prone. But in this case the only two imports on demand are `java.util.*` and `java.io.*` of those two, only java.util contains Iterator, so why should that be the problem?

Comment: @SteelToe OK. I have got it to work with your suggestion to use a wildcard version and then cast `it` as `Node` Object but still no clue why it is an issue on OSX when on Windows was not.

Comment: I believe it is a bug that for some reason the iterator that is returned when running on mac does is not using a generic object that subclasses node, or it is some compiler bug. It's very weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be in the Iterator that is being returned with `sh.extractAllHeaderElements();` Instead of returning a `Iterator<Node>` it is returning a Iterator of some other type when run on the mac platform. Thus useing a wildcard with the Iterator interface will work.

To do this just replace the `Iterator<Node> it = sh.extractAllHeaderElements();` with `Iterator<?> it = sh.extractAllHeaderElements();`